# My activity is unable to connect to website and display JSON data using volley

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I have been trying to use volley to connect and parse JSON data in an activity as posted below but each time the application forces close. The value of urlJsonObj is correct since it displays the data when i call it from a browser. Where am i doing it wrong?

```
 package gsie.bizlink;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.GridView;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.android.volley.DefaultRetryPolicy;
    import com.android.volley.Request;
    import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
    import com.android.volley.Response;
    import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
    import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
    import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
    import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
    import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
    import com.loopj.android.http.JsonHttpResponseHandler;

    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;

    public class CinteretsActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

        private String prenom;
        private String nom;
        private String telephone1;
        private String telephone2;
        private String telephone3;
        private String email;
        private TextView myentries;

        private static final String urlJsonObj ="http://www.pmsgroom.net/bizlink/CinteretsServlet";
        private ArrayList<Cinteret> cinteretsList=new ArrayList<Cinteret>();
        private CinteretsAdapter cinteretsadapter;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_cinterets);

            //myentries=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);


            Intent in=getIntent();
            prenom=in.getStringExtra("prenom");
            nom=in.getStringExtra("nom");
            telephone1=in.getStringExtra("telephone1");
            telephone2=in.getStringExtra("telephone2");
            telephone3=in.getStringExtra("telephone3");
            email=in.getStringExtra("email");

            //myentries.setText(prenom+"\n"+nom+"\n"+telephone1+"\n"+telephone2+"\n"+telephone3+"\n"+email);
        //new JSONParse().execute();
        //cinteretsList=getList();
    /*
            AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
            client.get(urlJsonObj,
                    new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                            try {
                                JSONArray jarray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("cinterets");
                                String cinteretiden = "";
                                String cinterettext = "";
                                for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject cinteret = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                                    cinteretiden = cinteret.getString("cinteretid");
                                    cinterettext = cinteret.getString("cinterettxt");
                                    Cinteret cint = new Cinteret();
                                    cint.setId(cinteretiden);
                                    cint.setText(cinterettext);
                                    cinteretsList.add(cint);
                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                Log.d("jsonerror", "Error: " + e);
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable throwable, JSONObject error) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: " + statusCode + " " + throwable.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Log.e("bizlink android", statusCode + " " + throwable.toString());
                        }
                    });

    */
            //volley commence ici

            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                    urlJsonObj, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d("reponse", response.toString());

                    try {
                        JSONArray jarray=response.getJSONArray("cinterets");
                        String cinteretiden="";
                        String cinterettext="";
                        for(int i=0;i<jarray.length();i++){
                            JSONObject cinteret=jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                            cinteretiden = cinteret.getString("cinteretid");
                            cinterettext=cinteret.getString("cinterettxt");
                            Cinteret cint=new Cinteret();
                            cint.setId(cinteretiden);
                            cint.setText(cinterettext);
                            cinteretsList.add(cint);
                        }


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.d("jsonerror", "Error: " + e);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d("MainActivity", "Error: " + error);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            jsonObjReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(5000,5,1f));
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);

    //volley prend fin ici

   /*  
    if(cinteretsList==null || cinteretsList.isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Liste centres d'interet est vide!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d("reponse", "dedans");
        Cinteret ct=new Cinteret();
        ct.setId("1");
        ct.setText("immobilier");
        cinteretsList.add(ct);
        Cinteret ct2=new Cinteret();
        ct2.setId("2");
        ct2.setText("locations");
        cinteretsList.add(ct2);

    }
    */    
    ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        cinteretsadapter = new CinteretsAdapter(this, cinteretsList);
        listview.setAdapter(cinteretsadapter);
        Button valid=(Button) findViewById(R.id.finirbtn);
            valid.setOnClickListener(this);
       }
        /*public ArrayList<Cinteret> getList(){
            final ArrayList<Cinteret> ci=new ArrayList<Cinteret>();
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                    urlJsonObj, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d("reponse", response.toString());

                    try {
                        JSONArray jarray=response.getJSONArray("cinterets");
                        String cinteretiden="";
                        String cinterettext="";
                        for(int i=0;i<jarray.length();i++){
                            JSONObject cinteret=jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                            cinteretiden = cinteret.getString("cinteretid");
                            cinterettext=cinteret.getString("cinterettxt");
                            Cinteret cint=new Cinteret();
                            cint.setId(cinteretiden);
                            cint.setText(cinterettext);
                            ci.add(cint);
                        }


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.d("jsonerror", "Error: " + e);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Error: " + e.toString(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d("MainActivity", "Error: " + error);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            //AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
            jsonObjReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(50000,
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
             queue.add(jsonObjReq);

            if(ci.size()==0 || ci==null){
                Log.d("reponse", "dedans");
                Cinteret ct=new Cinteret();
                ct.setId("1");
                ct.setText("immobilier");
                ci.add(ct);
                Cinteret ct2=new Cinteret();
                ct2.setId("2");
                ct2.setText("locations");
                ci.add(ct2);
            }
            return ci;
        }*/
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_cinterets, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ArrayList<String> cinteretTextList=cinteretsadapter.getSelectedString();
            ArrayList<String> cinteretIdList=cinteretsadapter.getSelectedId();
            String cinteretTextStr="";
            for (int i=0;i<cinteretTextList.size();i++){
                cinteretTextStr=cinteretTextStr+cinteretTextList.get(i)+"\n";
            }
            Intent in=new Intent(this,ConfirmInscriptionActivity.class);
            in.putExtra("prenom",prenom);
            in.putExtra("nom", nom);
            in.putExtra("telephone1", telephone1);
            in.putExtra("telephone2",telephone2);
            in.putExtra("telephone3",telephone3);
            in.putExtra("email",email);
            in.putExtra("cinterets",cinteretTextStr);
            startActivity(in);

        }


    /*/debut paste
     private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
             private ProgressDialog pDialog;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(CinteretsActivity.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Chargement ...");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                pDialog.show();

            }

            @Override
            protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
                JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

                JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(urlJsonObj);
                return json;
            }
             @Override
             protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
                 pDialog.dismiss();
                 try {
                            JSONArray jarray=json.getJSONArray("cinterets");
                            String cinteretiden="";
                            String cinterettext="";
                            for(int i=0;i<jarray.length();i++){
                                JSONObject cinteret=jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                                cinteretiden = cinteret.getString("cinteretid");
                                cinterettext=cinteret.getString("cinterettxt");
                                Cinteret cint=new Cinteret();
                                cint.setId(cinteretiden);
                                cint.setText(cinterettext);
                                cinteretsList.add(cint);
                            }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.d("jsonerror", "Error: " + e);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

             }
        }
    end paste*/


    }
```

My appController.java is:

```
public class AppController extends Application {

    public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    private static AppController mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }
}
```

here is the logcat

```
06-30 17:03:42.996  20691-20715/gsie.bizlink I/SurfaceTextureClient﹕ [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x52f520e8) fps:2.10, dur:1428.35, max:497.07, min:434.57
06-30 17:03:42.997    144-14142/? I/BufferQueue﹕ [gsie.bizlink/gsie.bizlink.ContactsActivity](this:0x41b41a80,api:1) [queue] fps:2.10, dur:1428.42, max:497.07, min:434.69
06-30 17:03:43.006      144-234/? I/BufferQueue﹕ [gsie.bizlink/gsie.bizlink.ContactsActivity](this:0x41b41a80,api:1) [release] fps:2.10, dur:1428.57, max:496.91, min:434.77
06-30 17:03:43.172     517-1530/? I/ActivityManager﹕ START u0 {cmp=gsie.bizlink/.CinteretsActivity (has extras)} from pid 20691
06-30 17:03:43.222      517-534/? I/WindowManager﹕ Losing focus: Window{4212d2d8 u0 gsie.bizlink/gsie.bizlink.ContactsActivity}
06-30 17:03:43.329  20691-20691/gsie.bizlink D/AbsListView﹕ checkAbsListViewlLogProperty get invalid command
06-30 17:03:43.337  20691-20691/gsie.bizlink D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
06-30 17:03:43.337  20691-20691/gsie.bizlink W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40d4b9a8)
06-30 17:03:43.344  20691-20691/gsie.bizlink E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{gsie.bizlink/gsie.bizlink.CinteretsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2372)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2424)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5400)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:837)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:604)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at gsie.bizlink.CinteretsActivity.onCreate(CinteretsActivity.java:149)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2336)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2424)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5400)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:837)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:604)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-30 17:03:43.354      517-783/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Force finishing activity gsie.bizlink/.CinteretsActivity
06-30 17:03:43.356      517-783/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Force finishing activity gsie.bizlink/.ContactsActivity
06-30 17:03:43.436      517-534/? I/WindowManager﹕ Gaining focus: Window{42218480 u0 Application Error: gsie.bizlink}
06-30 17:03:43.459      144-234/? I/BufferQueue﹕ [Application Error: gsie.bizlink](this:0x41b25008,api:0) setConsumerName: Application Error: gsie.bizlink
06-30 17:03:43.470    517-21594/? D/AES﹕ process : gsie.bizlink
06-30 17:03:43.470    517-21594/? D/AES﹕ module : gsie.bizlink v1 (1.0)
06-30 17:03:43.471      144-234/? I/BufferQueue﹕ [Application Error: gsie.bizlink](this:0x41b25008,api:0) setDefaultBufferSize: w=480, h=190
06-30 17:03:43.475    517-21594/? D/AEE/LIBAEE﹕ shell: raise_exp(2, 20691, -1361051648, gsie.bizlink, 0x0x5f14cae0, 0x0x0)
06-30 17:03:43.479    144-12221/? I/BufferQueue﹕ [Application Error: gsie.bizlink](this:0x41b25008,api:0) connect: api=2
06-30 17:03:43.479    144-12221/? I/BufferQueue﹕ [Application Error: gsie.bizlink](this:0x41b25008,api:2) setSynchronousMode: enabled=1
06-30 17:03:43.479    144-12932/? I/BufferQueue﹕ [Application Error: gsie.bizlink](this:0x41b25008,api:2) new GraphicBuffer needed
06-30 17:03:43.503      144-234/? I/SurfaceTexture﹕ [Application Error: gsie.bizlink](this:0x417f7798,api:2) [void* android::SurfaceTexture::createImage(EGLDisplay, const android::sp<android::GraphicBuffer>&)]
06-30 17:03:43.856      517-532/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{422b2d48 u0 gsie.bizlink/.CinteretsActivity}
06-30 17:03:49.201      144-543/? I/BufferQueue﹕ [Application Error: gsie.bizlink](this:0x41b25008,api:2) new GraphicBuffer needed
06-30 17:03:49.210    144-22775/? I/BufferQueue﹕ [Application Error: gsie.bizlink](this:0x41b25008,api:2) [queue] fps:0.17, dur:5717.39, max:5717.39, min:5717.39
06-30 17:03:49.217      144-234/? I/SurfaceTexture﹕ [Application Error: gsie.bizlink](this:0x417f7798,api:2) [void* android::SurfaceTexture::createImage(EGLDisplay, const android::sp<android::GraphicBuffer>&)]
06-30 17:03:49.217    144-14673/? I/BufferQueue﹕ [Application Error: gsie.bizlink](this:0x41b25008,api:2) new GraphicBuffer needed
06-30 17:03:49.232      144-234/? I/SurfaceTexture﹕ [Application Error: gsie.bizlink](this:0x417f7798,api:2) [void* android::SurfaceTexture::createImage(EGLDisplay, const android::sp<android::GraphicBuffer>&)]
06-30 17:03:53.222      517-532/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Activity idle timeout for ActivityRecord{422b2d48 u0 gsie.bizlink/.CinteretsActivity}
06-30 17:03:53.859      517-532/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Activity idle timeout for ActivityRecord{421fd170 u0 gsie.bizlink/.IdentificationActivity}
06-30 17:04:03.226      517-532/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{42551e40 u0 gsie.bizlink/.ContactsActivity}
06-30 17:04:03.229      517-532/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{422b2d48 u0 gsie.bizlink/.CinteretsActivity}
```

my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="gsie.bizlink" >
       <uses-sdk
        android:targetSdkVersion="22"
        android:minSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:name=".AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".IdentificationActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_identification" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ContactsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_contacts" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".CinteretsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_cinterets" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ConfirmInscriptionActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_confirm_inscription" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: can you show the logcat ...?

Comment: it is not showing any error message. Just too much output when it is verbose

Comment: you said that its forced close..then there can be any excpetion just check logcat properly by filtering only error ..

Comment: applicatations are not able to force close without exception stacktrace. You have to post it here if you want help.

Comment: please see edit for logcat

Comment: @PaulNgom No one can help you debug without the logcat.

Comment: i have added the logcat

Comment: Do you have INTERNET permission into AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: @JaredBurrows I did a mistake on the first post. So i have now posted the correct message.

Comment: Can you open the JSON URL `urlJsonObj` straight from the device's browser?

Comment: @Markus yes it can open

Comment: Well then this is really weird. Everything seems to be fine in your code. Please double-check AndroidManifest.xml to have internet permission and then double-check the url hostname and port for typo. Try a clean build / clean install too (uninstall old apk from device before installing clean build).

Comment: @Markus i have done the checks and re-installed but the problem is still there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81576/discussion-between-markus-and-paul-ngom).

Comment: it could be that the server is expecting certain header / content type values which the browser is providing, but volley is not. Any chance to get the url to test here? If not, perhaps you could attach Chrome's dev console output for the network activity on this request?

Comment: private final String urlJsonObj ="http://www.pmsgroom.net/bizlink/CinteretsServlet";

Comment: the protocol http:// is part of the url

Comment: i have tried loopj, AsynckTask but i am unable to get the json data

Comment: The signature for the method on succes in loopj is wrong if you are using the version1.4.7 try with: public void onSuccess(int statusCode,
                                          org.apache.http.Header[] headers,JSONObject jsonObject)

Comment: i have used com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.4

Comment: can anyone test the code with the url i have supplied, please?

Comment: try this `jsonObjReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(5000,5,1f));` let me know if it works. It works with Volley.

Comment: I have a Runtime NullPointerException. jsonObjReq is null.

Comment: Can you post the full `CinteretsActivity.java` file?

Comment: The logical suggests error @ line number 149, can u post the entire file ?

Comment: @PaulNgom did you add <application
        android:name=".AppController" to the Manifest?

Comment: @isma3l no, i did not. Where in the manifest should i add it?

Comment: @PaulNgom I put an example as answer because it's easier to read, if it doesn't work i'll just delete the answer

Comment: @PaulNgom now as per the CinteretsActivity.java, logs should have changed . Line#149 won't give a null pointer as per the code.

Comment: I have populated cinteretsList to avoid the null pointer but that data is static. If i remove it i will have the null pointer on this line 149 AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);

Comment: @PaulNgom do you still have the problem?

Answer (score 2):

As I can see you code, you forgot to initialize the `cinteretsList`. So you must do something like the following code before `for`:

```
ArrayList<Cinteret> cinteretsList = new ArrayList<Cinteret>();
```

Comment: You have to pay attention why your `mInstance ` is null when you call `AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);`. Debug your code and see what is happening in each line.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the AppController in the Manifest.xml

```
<manifest ....
    <application
        android:name=".AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
       ...
        </activity>
    </application>
    //permissions
</manifest>
```

Comment: No improvement! The list cinteretsList is still empty.

Comment: @PaulNgom you don't notify the adapter after you receive the data, if you receive the json, example:  clear the adapter, cinteretsadapter.clear(), then add the data in the for loop, cinteretsadapter.add(cint), then after the loop you call cinteretsadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: the data is not received that is why it is throwing a null pointer here AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);

Answer (score 2):

Please set adapter after the call to the server, i can fill the listView check the gist

https://gist.github.com/imjarp/572ada5ee51d95020e3c

[image: ListView Image]